# Airflow Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 1

Tags: python, jar, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

I am trying to execute dataflow jar through airflow script. For it i am using DataFlowJavaOperator. In the param jar,i am passing the path of the executable jar file present in the local system.But when i try to run this job i get error as

```
{gcp_dataflow_hook.py:108} INFO - Start waiting for DataFlow process to complete.
[2017-09-12 16:59:38,225] {models.py:1417} ERROR - DataFlow failed with return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 116, in execute
    hook.start_java_dataflow(self.task_id, dataflow_options, self.jar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 146, in start_java_dataflow
    task_id, variables, dataflow, name, ["java", "-jar"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 138, in _start_dataflow
    _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 119, in wait_for_done
    self._proc.returncode))
Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 1`
```

My airflow script is :

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowJavaOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'start_date': datetime(2017, 03, 16),
'email': [<EmailID>],

'dataflow_default_options': {
        'project': '<ProjectId>',
       # 'zone': 'europe-west1-d', (i am not sure what should i pass here)
        'stagingLocation': 'gs://spark_3/staging/'
    }
 }

 dag = DAG('Dataflow',schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=2), 
 default_args=default_args)

 dataflow1 = DataFlowJavaOperator(
 task_id='dataflow_example',
 jar ='/root/airflow_scripts/csvwriter.jar',
 gcp_conn_id  = 'GCP_smoke', 
 dag=dag)
```

I am not sure what mistake i am making ,Can anybody please help me to get out of this

`Note :I am creating this jar while selecting option as Runnable JAR file by packaging all the external dependencies.`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the jar that I was using. Before using the jar, Make sure that the jar is executing as expected.

**Example:** 
If your jar was dataflow_job1.jar, Execute the jar using

```
java -jar dataflow_job_1.jar --parameters_if_any
```

Once your jar runs successfully, Proceed with using the jar in Airflow DataflowJavaOperator jar.

**Furthermore,** 
If you encounter errors related to Coders, you may have to make your own coder to execute the code. 
For instance, I had a problem with TableRow class as it didnot have a default coder and thus i had to make this up:

TableRowCoder :

```
public class TableRowCoder extends Coder<TableRow> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Coder<TableRow> tableRow = TableRowJsonCoder.of();
@Override
public void encode(TableRow value, OutputStream outStream) throws CoderException, IOException {
    tableRow.encode(value, outStream);

}
@Override
public TableRow decode(InputStream inStream) throws CoderException, IOException {
    return new TableRow().set("F1", tableRow.decode(inStream));
}
@Override
public List<? extends Coder<?>> getCoderArguments() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void verifyDeterministic() throws org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.NonDeterministicException {


}
}
```

Then Register this coder in your code using

```
pipeline.getCoderRegistry().registerCoderForClass(TableRow.class, new TableRowCoder())
```

If there are still errors(which are not related to coders) Navigate to:

```
*.jar\META-INF\services\FileSystemRegistrar
```

and add any dependencies that may occur.

For example there might be a staging error as:

```
Unable to find registrar for gs
```

i had to add the following line to make it work.

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystemRegistrar
```